# refresh tableView after deleting cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tableView with data populated from Firebase, when I click a delete button the data is removed from Firebase but it remains on my app and it doesn't remove the data from the tableView until I close the app and reopen it. Here is how I set up the delete function:

```
func deletePost() {
        let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com")
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let indexPath = self.selectedIndex

            let post = self.posts[(indexPath?.row)!] as! [String: AnyObject]
            self.key = post["postID"] as? String

            self.itemsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).child(self.key!)


        // Remove the post from the DB
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("books").child(self.key!).removeValue { error in
            if error != nil {
                print("error \(error)")
            }
        }

            })
        self.TableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Here are the delegate and datasource:

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
            return 1
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         posts.count
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       self.selectedIndex = indexPath
        self.didExpandCell()
        if isExpanded && self.selectedIndex == indexPath{
            print(indexPath)
        } else{
                    }}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if isExpanded && self.selectedIndex == indexPath{
            return 300
        }
              return 126
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell

        //Configure the cell
        let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
        cell.Title.text = post["title"] as? String
        cell.Author.text = post["Author"] as? String
        cell.ISBN10.text = post["ISBN10"] as? String
        return cell
    }
```

I attempted to add a tableview.reloaddata at the end of the function but that doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post your tableview delegate and data source functions, as this information is not enough to help!

Comment: You need to call reloadData() in the callback of removeValue.

Comment: @SteffenSchmitz that's not working either

Comment: Could you please post the rest of the controller then? Especially where you assign the tableView delegate and the delegate implementation?

Comment: Remove your object from `posts` array and then reload your tableview in main queue one you remove your object from firebase.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni can you please show me how to do that in an answer

Comment: @juelizabeth sure will do.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your object from `posts` array and then reload your `tableView` in main queue one you remove your object from firebase.

Check below code:

```
func deletePost() {
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
    let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com")
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let indexPath = self.selectedIndex

        let post = self.posts[(indexPath?.row)!] as! [String: AnyObject]
        self.key = post["postID"] as? String

        self.itemsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).child(self.key!)


        // Remove the post from the DB
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("books").child(self.key!).removeValue { error in
            if error != nil {
                print("error \(error)")
            } else {
                //Here remove your object from table array
                self.posts.remove(at: indexPath?.row)
                //Reload your tableview in main queue
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.TableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }

    })
}
```

Didn't tested it so let me know if you still have issue with above code.

Comment: i'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong but the cell still remains after I delete it

Comment: can you share any demo project? or check with print after deleting your object.

Comment: @juelizabeth Try to add a child in the firebase console afterwards. You register an EventListener to ".childAdded" in the deletePost function. The removeValue method is only invoked after you called deletePost and a child is added.

Comment: @SteffenSchmitz i'm not really sure how to do that

Comment: @juelizabeth try to remove the `    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
` part around the delete block. As you don't use snapshot in your code you shouldn't need it. I'm not sure when .childAdded is called, but this might be an issue.

Comment: @SteffenSchmitz actually I do need that piece of code because I use it to get the path of the post I need to delete. I used it to get self.key

Comment: @SteffenSchmitz i deleted the piece of code but the problem still remains

Comment: @juelizabeth Have you tried to place a debugger flag in the else clause and validate that self.posts contains the correct posts? Maybe the deletion from the array is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

```
        func deletePost() {
                let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
                let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com")
                FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

                    let indexPath = self.selectedIndex

                    let post = self.posts[(indexPath?.row)!] as! [String: AnyObject]
                    self.key = post["postID"] as? String

                    self.itemsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).child(self.key!)


                // Remove the post from the DB
                FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("books").child(self.key!).removeValue { error in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error \(error)")
                        return // use return here or use if else
                    }
// no error has occurred,hence move on to remove the post from the array
              self.posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
 }     })
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.TableView.reloadData()
                 }

            }
```

Comment: You should also reload the data in callback.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the removed object from your array also. Your table view gets populated using `posts` array, not from Firebase object itself. when you click delete button the data is removed from Firebase but it remains on your app, as you have not deleted that object from your array i.e. `posts` thats why it doesn't remove the data from the tableView until you close the app and reopen it.

You need the remove the deleted object from your posts array and reload that rows to get the effect.

```
 self.posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

and then reload that specific row itself.

```
 self.tableView.beginUpdates
 tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
 self.tableView.endUpdates;
```

In your case

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("books").child(self.key!).
   removeValue { error in
        if error != nil {
            print("error \(error)")
        } else{
          self.posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
          self.tableView.beginUpdates
          tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
          self.tableView.endUpdates;
        }
    }
  })
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Comment: when i put `self.tableView.beginUpdates` in the deletePost function I get expression resolves to an unused function

Comment: This is what I do in order to run it `self.posts.remove(at: indexPath?.row)
        
                self.TableView.beginUpdates()
                self.TableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .top);
                self.TableView.endUpdates();`