# Remove key-values with Firebase. iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can remove keys from Firebase and update the table. However once I get to the last one the cell doesn't get removed. I have counted the array inside the table after each delete and it shows there is always one despite the database removing the key. Only until I restart the app then the table is empty. I have looked at this answer: [Swift: 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960853/swift-attempt-to-delete-row-0-from-section-0-which-only-contains-0-rows-before) and [refresh tableView after deleting cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858791/refresh-tableview-after-deleting-cell) but it doesn't solve my issue.

Here is my `commit editingStyle`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        let attendee = AttendeeManager.shared.attendees[indexPath.row]

        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users/\(uid)/meetList/\(attendee.key!)")

        databaseRef.removeValue(completionBlock: { (_, _) in
            print(AttendeeManager.shared.attendees.count)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

This is my data structure example:

```
{
  "users": {
    "Juoiuf0N6FNDn3rYlM6X6UK62": {
      "meetList": {
        "DCVBHGVnvjfgvmfkgjgwgkgjffjg": true,
        "C076OYmVTzJF22HB3ggjftY2XpED2": true,
        "DhkgjrlorTKKjhrgkegfwmdhffwn": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: `AttendeeManager` is a singleton that manages the `Attendee` object.

Comment: no if you remove last node and node don't gets it's endpoint then firebase take that node as null and remove it.

Comment: Yes, the node is removed, but the tableView still displays the last cell.

Comment: You don't need reloadData() it call's it for you after removing the cell.

Comment: tableview might not getting refresh. try to reloadData in completionBlock when error as well.

Comment: It is being called inside the completionBlock, @sschunara have you tried this?

Comment: also make sure you are deleting it from the tableview's source as well as the database. yourdatasource.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row), then tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

Comment: @Ercell0 This works, but it is deleting multiple cells rather than just the one cell